# dart - its_all_about_you tutorial error

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am trying to run the latest version of its_all_about_you with the latest version of Dart Editor/SDK and I am getting this error. I copied the latest source from [github](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/web/target09/its_all_about_you)

```
Internal error: 'http://.../web/out/packages/web_ui/src/linked_list.dart': 
Error: line 72 pos 29: cannot resolve class name 'IterableBase' from 'LinkedList'
class LinkedList<E> extends IterableBase<E> {
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it? And for future reference how would one go about debugging the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a version mismatch. Could you please verify that your sdk (comes with the editor) is up to date.
If the error persists after an upgrade, post the version number of your editor and try the following (untested) example:

```
import 'dart:collection';
class A extends IterableBase { get iterator => null; }
main() { new A(); }
```

In recent versions of Dart this should work.